# Multiple columns and get unique on preferred column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to get 3 columns only if a preferred column is unique.

What is the correct syntax in Google Sheets?

```
=Query('Sales'!A:AX,"Select A, B, C where A is unique")
```

Comment: Hey, can you tell us more ? what are you trying to achieve ? Don't hesitate to share with us a dummy sheet with some sample data or some screenshot with the desired result. Thanks !

Comment: Hey there! I've created a sample data here. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IBcNCWeax_3s2LLDt8p2a98D3CrZTqYyB9gWNStaPnw/edit?usp=sharing)

The result of the query can be seen on `query result` tab. That's I want to achieve.

I use query because I'm getting the data on another file not on the same file.